# wp-admin hangs after trying to update a file via the editor

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

My Wordpress site has run without a hitch until now. I just tried to make a an edit to a template file via **Appearance** -> **Editor**. When I tried to update the file wp-admin started to hang. It is just sitting there now. I am running a VPS, so I restarted the container and it did nothing. I removed the file I tried to update, and still nothing. Any ideas how I can get my wp-admin working again?

Thanks!

Tre

Comment: Does the site run outside of the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on WP_DEBUG in your config file - just paste this in:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

White screen is an error, but the message is being surpressed. If that doesn't show anything still, find `display_errors` in your php.ini and set it to on.

You should be able to figure it out after that.